# make .py file executable in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04

I am running ubuntu 15.04. I have a simple python programme test.py

```
#!/user/bin/python
print "hello, python"
```

I want to make test.py file executable. Currently when i try to run the file using ./test.py commant its showing

bash: ./test.py: /user/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

> whereis python

command showing the following thing result

> python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.4
>   /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.4 /etc/python
>   /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python2.7
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/include/python2.7
>   /usr/include/python3.4m /usr/share/python
>   /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Answer (score 3):

Correct one is :

for python 2x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
   ^^^
  usr not user
```

for python 3x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

you also need to give your file executable permission

```
chmod u+x test.py
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `#!/usr/bin/python` not `user`

To find the full path of your python interpreter, run this command `which python` and it'll give you something like `/usr/bin/python`.